# Upper bound on the expectation of a random variable indexed by a random variale

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Imagine that we are given $X(u)$, a random variable indexed by some parameter $u \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, assume that we know that:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(|X(u)|)\leq 1 \quad \text{$\forall$ $u\in I$.}
\end{equation*}
Now, let $\theta$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}(\theta \in I) = 1$. We do not suppose that $\theta$ and $X(u)$ are independent.
Does it hold that:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(|X(\theta)|)\leq 1 \quad \text{?}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I think my brain just exploded :D. So in general, we start with a joint proability distribution $P[X, \theta]$, given by a CDF $\rho_u(X, \theta)$, where $u$ is a free parameter, and for which the CDF $\rho_u(X)$ is a marginal. Now we want to define a new CDF, using the previous CDF, except the free parameter now is also $\theta$. That feels quite illegal, but I fail to pinpoint what exactly is wrong with it. It feels like it should not be possible to define a free parameter used in the definition of a probability distribution through one of the variables the distribution is already defining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *At least one declared downvote for extramathematical reasons, by user @stuartstevenson. This sucks.*

The result does not hold without independence, as the simple example below shows.

Consider the parameter space $I=[0,1)$ and the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ defined by $\Omega=[0,1)$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\Omega)$, and $P$ the Lebesgue measure restricted to $\Omega$.

For every $u$ in $I$ and $\omega$ in $\Omega$, let $X(u)(\omega)=2\cos^2(2\pi(\omega+u))$. For every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, let $\theta(\omega)=1-\omega$.

Then, $E(X(u))=1$ for every $u$ in $I$ but the random variable $Y=X(\theta)$ is, by definition, such that $Y(\omega)=X(1-\omega)(\omega)=2$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$ hence $E(Y)=2$.

Answer (score 3):

As Did says, this is false.

Suppose that $I=\{0,1\}$ and $X(u)$ and $\theta$ are determined by a fair coin toss:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{heads}&\implies X(0)=2, X(1)=0, \theta=0\\
\text{tails}&\implies X(0)=0, X(1)=2, \theta=1
\end{align}
$$

Then $E(X(0))=E(X(1))=1$ and $E(X(\theta))=2$.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it holds.

If $\theta \in I$ with probability $1$ then $\theta \in I$.

The rest follows from definition.

The only issue I might see is if this is in some kind of limiting sense in which case you might use the suffix, "in the limit" or "almost surely" depending on the context.

Comment: Should we expect some correction or deletion of this, presently wrong, answer?